# Isekai manga about a boy who gets reincarnated in the body of a child in a duke's or count's family

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's an *isekai* manga about a boy who gets reincarnated in the body of a child in a duke's or count's family. He and his mother get mistreated by the main wife and her child. After the mom of the MC divorces his dad, he finds out his mom is actually a princess and that makes him royalty by default.

Comment: does he reincarnated into a girl or not

Comment: Could you please add some details if you remember enough to be more precise? Does the MC have any abilities inherent to his reincarnation? Do you remember what happens next in the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it: *[Maseki Gurume: Mamono no Chikara o Tabeta Ore wa Saikyou!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=154663)*?

> In this world, It's only me who can get stronger by eating Magic Stones! 
> At one point, I received an offer to have a smooth life reincarnation from the Goddess-sama... But the skill I got as a prize is Toxins Decomposition EX. Ugh, what a plain skill! Its so pitiful that even my own family makes fun of me... 
> However, one day I realized that because of this skills effect, I can eat and gain power from Magic Stones! I've also been notified that I'm the prince from a neighboring country!? What awaits me in the castle are days of experimenting with Magic Stones and training, the perfect environment for me to become the strongest man there is... 
> And to top it off, I received the Magic Stone of Dullahan! 
> The story of a boy on the path to become a King while being chased by an assertive fiancee and Female Knights starts here!

Comment: I've added a link and a summary from it as some basic information about the manga. Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP's description and why you think it is what they are looking for?

Comment: it is Maseki Gurume: Mamono no Chikara o Tabeta Ore wa Saikyou! Thank You!