# Isekai manga where the main character dies and is reincarnated as a prince in another world/country

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I know of a manga where the main character died and woke up as a prince in another world/country. He was deemed useless, but was always protected and taken care of by a girl (his fiancée), and the nobles controlled the city from behind.

But then he can go into a game world to level up, and I think it has a timer for how long he can remain in the other world to train. Each time he grows and attains a new job title, and supposedly obtains all possible job titles like paladin, etc.

I think the church held much power, but he was able to control that aspect related to his city. There's also a strong female knight in his city. And the beginning was when a demon prince wanted to conquer his city.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you clarify roughly when did you read this? It'll help us to eliminate newer stories.

Comment: This sounds similar to this post. Could it be the same? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227722/isekai-manga-about-a-boy-who-gets-reincarnated-in-the-body-of-a-child-in-a-duke

Comment: i read it last year

Comment: Would you say that the manga series might be tagged Harem, if not that would exclude a lot of options. What about Ecchi? Was the fantasy kingdom eastern or western? Is there anything specific about the reincarnation? Did the fantasy world or the game world have magic?

Answer (score 1):

The manga you are searching for sounds like [**"Long Live the King"**](https://anilist.co/manga/116452/Guowang-Wansui), so maybe its that?

The summary is: An ordinary student accidentally (he died) traveled to another world and became the king of a small kingdom. He started off not as a prince but rather a king and he was deemed useless in the beginning. Like you searched and in the manga he can also travel to the game world to get stronger gaining titles with the system. He was also protected by his fiancée almost all the time. There is also a strong female knight. and at the beginning a demon prince really did want to conquer the city. So its pretty much what you are looking for besides the fact that the main character isn't a prince but rather a king. Right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe the manga you're talking about, perhaps link to some information about it, and explain how it matches the question?  Just giving the name and expecting people to have to do the research themselves doesn't make for a very good answer; the answer should be complete and stand on its own.  You might want to read [answer].